# How to validate a form without reloading the page and keep inhidden div intact?javascript, php, ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, post

Got a problem with my program. Need help. I unhide a div element on a click of a button. The div contains a form. And of course, the form needs validating before using ajax to post something in the database. However, my main problem is that whenever I push submit to validate, using javascript, the page reloads, causing the div to hide again. I am having trouble with jquery, too. I mean, I am still learning jquery.

**css**

```
.divform{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

**javascript**

```
function unhide(){
  document.getElementById("divform").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function validateform(){
   //validation with focus() on if false
}
```

**html**

```
<input type='button' onclick='unhide()' value='unhide'/>
<div class='divform' id='divform'>
  <form method='post' id='formid' name='formid' onsubmit='validateform();'>
  <label>Name: </label> <input type='text' name='name' id='name'/>
  <!-- more input type here-->
  <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'/>
  </form>
</div>
```

How do i submit the form successfully without reloading the page and not causing the div to hide again? thanks, really need help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that haapens without reloading the page is using AJAX ....

Learn here [AJAX TUTORIALS](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/%E2%80%8E)

Another Specific Example is Given here : [AJAX FORM SUBMISSION EXAPMLE](http://www.simonerodriguez.com/ajax-form-submit-example/)